# Where to put a configuration file for an Axis2 web service?

Tags: web-services, configuration, apache-axis

I'd like to have my Axis2 Web Service read from a configuration file, whose name is sent as a parameter to the service.

Where is the best place to put this file? And How to best access it? Examples welcome.

I've checked the current directory is the Apache/Tomcat/bin file, I could put it in the parent directory, or put it into a Apache/Tomcat/conf, although this looks like it's more reserved for apache configuration itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to load a configuration file on each request, which means configuration needs to be loaded ideally on startup.

In my experience that leaves you with two choices:

- Embedded Spring container
- JNDI

The former approach is described in the Axis2 [documentation](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_5_1/spring.html), the latter approach depends on the appserver/container you're using.

An example if JNDI configuration for jetty is [here:](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/JNDI)